# TypeError: (0, _native.createNavigatorFactory) is not a function

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation, mobile-development

I don't understand what the issue is first I'm using react-native-drawer v4 but after I'm trying to use '@react-navigation/drawer' v5 but it's not working. Someone who can help me with what mistake I'm doing.
I'm using expo-CLI for the react-native app.

Reason to move on v5 I feel easy to add custom button or options because I don't found who to add custom drawer option in v4.

```
import React from 'react';
// import { createDrawerNavigator,   DrawerContentScrollView,  DrawerItemList, DrawerItem, } from 'react-navigation-drawer';
import {createDrawerNavigator,DrawerContentScrollView,DrawerItemList,    DrawerItem,} from '@react-navigation/drawer';



const AuthNavigation = createDrawerNavigator({
    Login:{screen:Login},
});
function CustomDrawerContent(props) {
    return (
      <DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>
        <DrawerItemList {...props} />
        <DrawerItem label="logout" onPress={() => alert('Link to help')} />
      </DrawerContentScrollView>
    );
  }
  
  const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
  
  function MyDrawer() {
    return (
      <Drawer.Navigator drawerContent={props => <CustomDrawerContent {...props} />}>
        <Drawer.Screen name="Users" component={AllUsers} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Data" component={AllData} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Add User" component={AddUser} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Uploader" component={UploadFile} />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    );
  }

// const AppNavigation = createDrawerNavigator({
//     Add_User:{
//         screen: AddUser,
//         navigationOptions:{
//             drawerLabel: 'Add User',
//         }
//     },
//     Data:{screen: AllData},
//     Users:{screen: AllUsers},
//     Uploader:{screen: UploadFile},
    
 
// })
const AuthLoadScreen = ({navigation}) =>{
    const _loadData= async ()=>{
        const isLoggedIn = await AsyncStorage.getItem('isLoggedIn'); 
        navigation.navigate(isLoggedIn !== '1' ? 'Auth':'App' );
    }
    _loadData();
    return(
       <View>
        <ActivityIndicator/>
        <StatusBar barStyle="default" />
       </View>
    );
}


export default createAppContainer(createSwitchNavigator(
    {
        AuthLoading:AuthLoadScreen,
        App:MyDrawer,
        Auth:AuthNavigation
    },{
        initialRouteName: 'AuthLoading'
    }
));
```

Comment: You are mixing navigation 4 and 5, you should use Navigation container if you are using V5

Answer (score 0):

Face same the same error. Got it resolved. Try with this:

```
npm install @react-navigation/native
```

or

```
yarn add @react-navigation/native@next
```

or

```
yarn add @react-navigation/native
```

Doc : https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started/